# How to get “HTTP_REFERER” with koa in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, koa

How can I get the referrer from the request object? The variable `this.request.headers['referer']` was empty.

Comment: Are you sure that there _is_ a referrer?

Comment: what about `this.request.headers.referrer || this.request.headers.referer`?

Comment: tried it with the 2 forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your page was referred by another page, the referer will be accessable through `this.headers.referer`.

If the page was not refered by another page (was loaded directly), `this.headers.referer` will be undefined.

This demo code:

```
'use strict'
const Koa = require('koa')
let app = new Koa()
app.use(function * () {
  console.log(this.headers)
})

app.listen(8888)
```

Yielded this when referred by another page:

```
{ host: 'localhost:8888',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  referer: 'http://localhost:1111/',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

And this when loaded directly:

```
{ host: 'localhost:8888',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

Comment: then my question had the answer also :)

Answer (score 2):

For newer koa versions - I currently use 2.5.1 - a warning is generated because of the generator function `*()`, so here's a newer example with ES6 syntax

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()
app
   .use(async (ctx) => console.log(ctx.request.headers))

app.listen(8888)
```

Output should be the same as described by @JoshWillik except the warning

Edit:

gif add that shows that it works [image]
and a [sample repository](https://github.com/amlang/koa-stackoverflow-example) to try out